# Need to identify duplicate Xpath values and then print them only once

Tags: xml, xslt, foreach, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

The output of my XML looks like this:

```
<Data>
    <Payment>
        <PayeeName>Jim</PayeeName>
        <CheckNumber>1</CheckNumber>
        <Account_group>
            <Account_Number>123456789</Account_Number>
        </Account_group>
    </Payment>
    <Payment>
        <PayeeName>Alex</PayeeName>
        <CheckNumber>2</CheckNumber>
        <Account_group>
            <Account_Number>123456789</Account_Number>
        </Account_group>
    </Payment>
    <Payment>
        <PayeeName>Zach</PayeeName>
        <CheckNumber>3</CheckNumber>
        <Account_group>
            <Account_Number>555566666</Account_Number>
        </Account_group>
    </Payment>
</Data>
```

And I need to transform it to look like this:

```
Account 123456789
CheckNumber 1 Jim
CheckNumber 2 Alex

Account 555566666
CheckNumber 3 Zach
```

Essentially I need to write my XSLT to detect when there is a duplicate "Account_Number" through out the entire XML file and then print that account number only once. Then I need to print all "Payments" associated with the account number in multiple lines under the single account number line. Sadly I cannot change the way in which the XML is outputting to make this easier.

I am having a hard time figuring out where to start.

I thought the solution would start with something like this:

```
    <xsl:template match="Data">
        <xsl:for-each select="Payment">
            <xsl:call-template name="AccountHeader"/
            <xsl:call-template name="DetailRecord"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="AccountHeader">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="Account_group" group by="Account_Number">
            <text>Account </text>
            <xsl:value-of select="Account_Number"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$linefeed" />
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template name="DetailRecord">  
        <xsl:for-each select="Payment"> 
            <text>CheckNumber </text>
            <xsl:value-of select="CheckNumber"/>
            <text> </text>
            <xsl:value-of select="PayeeName"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$linefeed" />
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
```

But the logic is obviously flawed here and it won't give me my expected outcome. Any leads on where to start would be highly appreciated.

*Hardcoded the static values and spaces for sake of example.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info

Comment: While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSLT stylesheet that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, or 4.0.
All within the question as text, no images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some syntax errors, as well as logic ones. Try it this way:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" />

<xsl:template match="/Data">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="Payment" group-by="Account_group/Account_Number">
        <xsl:text>Account </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
            <xsl:text>CheckNumber </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="CheckNumber"/>
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="PayeeName"/>
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```